# Compilation error for submission - UVA

Tags: java

i write this code for [UVA-Problem 100](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36)  and it works just fine in the IDE
but for submission i got this Compilation error:

> Main.java:5: class UVA100 is public, should be declared in a file
>   named UVA100.java public class UVA100 {
>          ^ 1 error

i'm newbie in java programming, and i have no idea to send this code in which format that is accepted by uva.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UVA100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, cnt, MAX, MIN, MaxCycle = 1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(input.hasNextInt()){            

        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();

        MAX = Math.max(a, b);
        MIN = Math.min(a, b);

        for (int i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++) {
            cnt=CalculateCycle(i);
            if(cnt>MaxCycle)
                MaxCycle=cnt;
        }

        System.out.print(a + " " + b + " " + MaxCycle);
        }
    }

    public static int CalculateCycle(int n) {
        int count = 1;
        while (n > 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
            } else {
                n = n * 3 + 1;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler error seems pretty clear to me. You've got a public class called `UVA100`, so it shouldn't be in a file called `Main.java` - it should be in `UVA100.java`.

Comment: not everyday do you see a comment by *the* @JonSkeet :-) Just hovering over his name gives you the shudder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer: [classes must nor be public in UVa](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=30) ;-)

> Java Specifications:
>   The Java programs submitted must be in a single source code (not .class) file. Nevertheless, you can add as many classes as you need in this file. All the classes in this file must not be within any package.
>
> All programs must begin in a static main method in a Main class.
>
> Do not use public classes: even Main must be non public to avoid compile error.
>
> Use buffered I/O to avoid time limit exceeded due to excesive flushing.
>
> As a reference, we provide a [sample Java code](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/data/p100.java.html)

Comment: Hi @Safeman, I guess without seeing the whole Main.java file, it's difficult to comment further. However, I guess that your class contained two top-level classes, as per: `public class Main {...} public class UVA100 {...}`. The general rule is that the filename should be the same as _the_ top-level class in the file. That is, have only one _top-level_ class per file and name the file after it. Follow this rule and you can't go far wrong (although I've checked the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html) and it's not actually in there which was a surprise.

Comment: Note that you typically only ever have one top-level class in a file in everyday dev (in my opinion). However, to further understand the intricacies if you wish: you must have only one top-level _public_ class; you can have multiple top-level _package-private_ classes; your top-level class cannot be private (what's the point if no one can use it); it also can't be protected (makes little sense to expose only to subclasses). I caveat all this by saying that it's likely to be a compiler detail as it's not described in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

A java class should be declared in a file named after the class name, irrespective if it contains a main() method or not.

So, your class should be called "UVA100.java" (as your class is named UVA100).

Which IDE did this work in as it's a javac (java compiler) error?

Without wanting to confuse the issue (as you've stated you're a newbie), "inner classes" may be declared in a java class but the class file should still be named after the top-level class.

**UPDATE**: Following OP response:

I guess without seeing the whole Main.java file, it's difficult to comment further. However, I guess that your class contained two top-level classes, as per:

```
public class Main {  //Top-level class Main
    ...
} 
public class UVA100 { //Top-level class UVA100 - not an inner class!
    ...
}
```

The general rule is that the filename should be the same as *the* top-level class in the file. That is, have only one *top-level* class per file and name the file after it. Follow this rule and you can't go far wrong (although I've checked the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html) and it's not actually in there which was a surprise). Note that you typically only ever have one top-level class in a file in everyday dev (in my opinion).

To further understand the intricacies if you wish:

- you must have only one top-level *public* class;
- you can have multiple top-level *package-private* classes;
- your top-level class cannot be private (what's the point if no one can use it);
- it also can't be protected (makes little sense to expose only to subclasses).

Confirmed using: java HotSpot version "1.7.0_11" (64-bit)

I caveat all this by saying that it's likely to be a compiler-specific detail as it's not described in the JLS.

Comment: i found the answer in this page: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=30